# Multiple touch events

Tags: android, multi-touch

I want to have four different areas on the screen and be able to determine if each of those areas are touched. Every area should have a corresponding boolean value that is true if touched. When one area is true that part of the canvas will become a different color.

It is very important that each area works independently, so if area 1 and two are true and the user lets go of area 1 it will instantly become false without affecting area 2.

Thanks!

Edit:
I've tried so many things but I've just started over again. This is from a class that has a SurfaceView with a canvas. I can't figure out what goes where.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        x = ev.getX();
        y = ev.getY();

        if (canvasHeight != 0 && canvasWidth != 0) {

            if (x < canvasWidth/2 && y < canvasWidth/2){
            x1 = x;
            y1 = y;

            }

            if (x < canvasWidth && y > canvasHeight){
                x2 = x;
                y2 = y;
            }
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried this far.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach your problem:

- Create rects that define the four regions of the screen that can be
  pressed.
- Using multi-touch, check if the coordinated are in any of the defined
  rects. If this is the case, then set the boolean value of that region
  of the screen to true, so a color will be rendered to that region. If
  the coordinate is not in the rect, then set the boolean to false.

I hope this gets you started!

**Update:**

I suggest you start off simple and don't use multitouch. In you touch method you can get the `x` and `y` value of the touch. Once the screen is touched you could call a method like this with x and y being your parameters eg. `checkRegion(x,y)`.

The method could return an int of the region (since in this case you can only touch one at a time):

```
public int checkRegion(int x, int y) {
int clickedRegion;

// Some code that will return the region number: 1 = top left, 2 = top right, 3 = bottom left, 4 = bottom right

return clickedRegion;

}
```

Comment: That was exactly how I was thinking! But the problem is to determine which square has been pressed and how to build the onTouch-method.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to check all four areas;

```
switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        x = ev.getX();
        y = ev.getY();

        if (canvasHeight != 0 && canvasWidth != 0) {
            //you need four sections, not the two?
            if (x < canvasWidth/2 && y < canvasWidth/2){
            //set your respective canvas color to what you want it for this quadrant
            }
            if (x < canvasWidth/2 && y > canvasWidth/2){
            //set your respective canvas color to what you want it for this quadrant
            }
            if (x < canvasWidth && y > canvasHeight){
                //set your respective canvas color to what you want it for this quadrant
            }
            if (x < canvasWidth && y < canvasHeight){
                //set your respective canvas color to what you want it for this quadrant
            }
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        break;
    }

        return true;
    }
```

Now, assuming you can get that to work, all you need to do is do it again in the action_pointer_down and it will register as a "secondary" click.

If the action is Action_up, just figure out where the user liftes his finger and do the same thing. One issue you should think about is this; what if a user clicks in Quadrant 1, but lifts it up in quadrant 3? That is a slightly more complicated condition, but I think you can skip it for now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Determine which quadrant the pointer is in is of course crucial but not that difficult. That is working fine right now.
What I don't really understand is how to register the second, third and fourth pointer. 
Do I do this in just ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, or do I have to add something in ACTION_MOVE?